# How do I properly cache a NSURLRequest in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, caching, uiwebview

Forgive if this has been asked but I've done heavy searching and can't seem to find an answer I'm looking for in swift. I have a `UIWebView` that loads PDF files and I wouldn't want the user to go through a tedious loading process again if they exit the WebView and come back, so how do I cache a request to make the loading quicker?

Here is my code:

```
var contentUrlPassedOn: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myWebView.delegate = self

        let url: NSURL! = NSURL(string: contentUrlPassedOn)

        myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
        var request: NSURLRequest
}
```

**UPDATE**

What I am trying to accomplish can be seen in [this video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2es7vg809vi8b22/cache.mov?dl=0)

that is an example of dropbox's iOS app. When one of the files have been already loaded, every other trip into that file ( in this case PDF) will be quick and easy. This method is exactly what I am trying to replicate.

any suggestions?

Comment: You can change the caching policy for NSURLRequest to NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad or NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData to favor using cached data. See this NSHipster article: http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/

Comment: PLEASE check my updated question, I have added a video that demonstrates exactly what I an trying to replicate  @DanNichols

Answer (score 5):

GIF

1. The first time you enter this ViewController,you can see download progress
2. Then second time, it just load local file.So it is very quick
   [image]

And code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate{
var sesson:NSURLSession!
var webview:UIWebView!
var progressView:UIProgressView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.sesson =   NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
    self.webview = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
    self.view.addSubview(webview)
    let documentDir = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask).first as! NSURL
    let pdfFilePath = documentDir.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Test.pdf");
    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(pdfFilePath.path!){
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: pdfFilePath)
        webview.loadRequest(request)
    }else{
        progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: UIProgressViewStyle.Default);
        progressView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,200, 4)
        progressView.progress = 0
        progressView.progressTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        progressView.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(progressView)
        let remoteURL = "https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.pdf"
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: remoteURL)!)
        let downloadTask = self.sesson.downloadTaskWithRequest(request)
        downloadTask.resume()
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
    if progressView != nil{
        progressView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    let documentDir = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask).first as! NSURL
    let pdfFilePath = documentDir.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Test.pdf");
    NSFileManager.defaultManager().moveItemAtURL(location, toURL: pdfFilePath, error: nil)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: pdfFilePath)
    self.webview.loadRequest(request)
}
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
    var curprogress = Float(totalBytesWritten)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
    progressView.progress = curprogress
}
}
```

Comment: wait is this saving the file from the app onto the computer or simply caching it in the app?

Comment: save the file to app sandbox. You see the picture,because I toke the sceenshot of simulator

Comment: It will be there until you delete it with code,if you want it to be auto delete,save it to cache directory of sandbox

Comment: well the thing is, I just don't want users to have to go through a whole load everytime they try to re-enter a PDF they were just in, what is the best option ?

Comment: PLEASE check my updated question, I have added a video that demonstrates exactly what I an trying to replicate

Comment: With the code I post,it is the second ViewController in the gif. In the first Controller, I just add a button to push the second ViewController

Comment: did you do any edits to the code? because i implemented it before and I had to go through the load again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89649/discussion-between-itzhak-ira-and-leo).

Comment: Do you have the same for a webpage in swift 3 using urlsession ? @leo

Answer (score 1):

NSURLConnection (and NSURLSession's shared session) uses a shared cache.  You can configure the policies of that cache to use on-disk storage, but my vague recollection is that iOS uses only an in-memory cache by default.  Have a look at the NSURLCache class, and do the Swift equivalent of:

```
NSString *myPath = ... // some subdirectory in your app's caches directory
NSURLCache *cache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithCapacity:2048576 /* 2M */
                                            diskCapacity: 134217728 /* 128M */
                                                    path:myPath];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:cache];
```

or whatever, and you'll probably have better luck.

Note that the on-disk cache in iOS is still temporary, and can be deleted by the OS, but only when your app is not running (assuming that hasn't changed recently).

Something like

```
let cacheDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.CachesDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
var dir = cacheDir.stringByAppendingFormat("/urlCache/")
var cache = NSURLCache(memoryCapacity: 2048576,
   diskCapacity: 134217728,
   path: dir)
NSURLCache.setSharedURLCache(cache)
```

but I'm not all that familiar with Swift, so I could be getting the syntax wrong.

Comment: You would typically do that exactly once, probably in your app's didFinishLaunching method or whatever, before your app starts opening web views.

Comment: so all I have to do is call that and it will cache my webView request to that subdirectory?

Comment: It should, yes.  At least I *think* WebKit uses the shared NSURL cache.  I'm not 100% certain.  It will either help or it won't.

Comment: so by any chance with the code in my question can you make a slight example?

Comment: Done, though I'm not too confident in my Swift syntax.

Comment: so where exactly are they getting cached? and Is this supposed to make the loading times faster for the WebView? because its partly similar

Comment: IIRC, they're getting cached in /path/to/your/app/sandbox/Library/Caches/urlCache/.  And I *think* it should work for UIWebView, because UIWebView just makes NSURLConnection requests for its URL handling, which should mean that it gains the benefit of that on-disk cache.

Comment: PLEASE check my updated question, I have added a video that demonstrates exactly what I an trying to replicate

Comment: and i've dug into my cache folder and found the url, however it says "zaro bytes on disk for 1 item"

Comment: IIRC, it won't get written to disk until it gets pushed out of the in-memory cache, so that's not necessarily indicative of a problem.  Are you sure that it is actually making a new request?  If so, are you sure that the server's caching policies allow the request to be cached?  Either way, if that doesn't work, odds are the only other option is to retrieve the data yourself, cache it yourself to a file on disk, and load it into the web view by calling the view's loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL: method

Comment: well the request are hosted from was s3, i not sure what their policy is

Comment: Look at the headers with curl -I http: //www.yourhostname.com/

Comment: ah, its says `Server: AWS Server
Cache-Control: private`